# What do the numbers on Mavis (Yonex) Badminton cocks mean?

Tags: equipment, terminology, badminton

I have seen sports shops selling Yonex Badminton cocks in boxes titled "Mavis 350", "Mavis 500" or "Mavis 10".

Do these numbers mean anything in particular, or is it just that the Brands can't get creative with their names?

I have tried to look into this a bit, and some say it may imply its **resemblance** to a feather cock. So a Mavis 2000 is **better** than a Mavis 10 in resembling a Yonex feather cock. Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YONEX offers [8 different plastic shuttlecock products](http://www.yonex.com/sports/badminton/products/badminton/shuttlecocks/nylon-shuttlecocks), although availability may differ depending on what region/country you're in. Depending on the market, some products may also not be available in white and yellow. Despite the [picture](http://www.yonex.com/_assets/images/cache/products/productmain/badminton-shuttlecocks-M2000-main.jpg) on the YONEX homepage, the 2000 *is* available in yellow.

The pricing and marketing suggests that the higher the number the better (= closer to feather shuttles) the flight path is.

Mavis 10 to Mavis 370 look very similar. In contrast, Mavis 2000 are visibly different, more so than it you can see in the official promotion pictures. (I have never handled 500 or 600.)

In my personal experience and opinion, Mavis 10, 350 and 370 feel quite similar. Anecdotally, the 10 breaks easier than the other ones, but I don't have enough data on that.

Mavis 2000 feels quite different than the other ones. I feel that you get more control at the net and there's a slightly larger range of distance (i.e. you can hit it out a little bit easier, but also play it quite slow), although that may be partially a placebo effect.

The Mavis 2000 breaks a little bit earlier than the 350/370, but it's still on the scale of a plastic shuttle; you can easily play multiple hours with a single shuttle.

Nevertheless, the difference between a Mavis 370 and 2000 is still less than between a Mavis 2000 and a feather shuttle.

If you want to stick to YONEX plastic shuttles and value good flight characteristics, the Mavis 2000 is certainly a good idea. If you want the plastic shuttle to fly like every other decent plastic shuttle, go for one of the other ones, e.g. a 350.

Comment: Just a side question to this, but what's the point of a mavis 10 if it shares the least similarity to a feather cock? Is it simply the cost?

Comment: Yes, I believe Mavis 10 are built cheaper. But it's likely that the difference is not more than a couple of cents. More importantly, offering (even slightly) different qualities allows YONEX to engage in [price discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_discrimination): Beginners who just want any shuttle (i.e. are looking just at the price) will buy the Mavis 10 (instead of a non-YONEX one), whereas more advanced players usually opt for 350 and upwards, because they are willing to pay more for a slight quality increase.

Comment: still not tried the 600?